# Generating the plural form of a noun

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet, linguistics

Given a word, which may or may not be a singular-form noun, how would you generate its plural form?

Based on this [NLTK tutorial](http://nltk.org/book/ch02.html) and this [informal list](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/330/grammar/irrplu.htm) on pluralization rules, I wrote this simple function:

```
def plural(word):
    """
    Converts a word to its plural form.
    """
    if word in c.PLURALE_TANTUMS:
        # defective nouns, fish, deer, etc
        return word
    elif word in c.IRREGULAR_NOUNS:
        # foot->feet, person->people, etc
        return c.IRREGULAR_NOUNS[word]
    elif word.endswith('fe'):
        # wolf -> wolves
        return word[:-2] + 'ves'
    elif word.endswith('f'):
        # knife -> knives
        return word[:-1] + 'ves'
    elif word.endswith('o'):
        # potato -> potatoes
        return word + 'es'
    elif word.endswith('us'):
        # cactus -> cacti
        return word[:-2] + 'i'
    elif word.endswith('on'):
        # criterion -> criteria
        return word[:-2] + 'a'
    elif word.endswith('y'):
        # community -> communities
        return word[:-1] + 'ies'
    elif word[-1] in 'sx' or word[-2:] in ['sh', 'ch']:
        return word + 'es'
    elif word.endswith('an'):
        return word[:-2] + 'en'
    else:
        return word + 's'
```

But I think this is incomplete. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without context. Did you know, sometimes the plural of "fish" is ["fishes"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fishes)?

Comment: @Kevin: Presumably the whole reason the OP wants to use WordNet is that it has a database with that information in it, and an API to use that database.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The pattern-en package offers [pluralization](https://github.com/clips/pattern/wiki/pattern-en#pluralization--singularization)

```
>>> import pattern.text.en
>>> pattern.text.en.pluralize("dog")
'dogs'
```

Note also that in order to run the import above successfully, you may have to first execute the following (at least the first time):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('omw-1.4')
```

Comment: I tried this with Python 3 and it seems like it is not supported. It was fairly easy however to copy the pluralize function from https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/pattern/text/en/inflect.py along with a copy of the license to get around the problem

Comment: I installed the pattern module as an egg for ease of distribution with my Python script, but it fails with the error `IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/path/to/eggs/Pattern-2.6-py2.7.egg/pattern/text/en/wordnet/dict/index.noun'` :-(

Comment: `soups` becomes `soupss`

Comment: It does have a few howlers (like quiz->quizs, but it knows quizzes->quiz). However, there is the possibility of passing a custom dict, so these can be handled without too much trauma. I think anything of this kind is bound to have a few errors - English is like that

Comment: Wow! A simple task of generating a plural form of noun comes with a price: the 'pattern' module pulls huge amount of dependencies!

Comment: In Python 3 this is  `import pattern.text.en`

Answer (score 28):

Another option which supports python 3 is [Inflect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect).

```
import inflect
engine = inflect.engine()
plural = engine.plural(your_string)
```

Answer (score 5):

First, it's worth noting that, as [the FAQ](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/database/) explains, WordNet cannot generate plural forms.

If you want to use it anyway, you can. With Morphy, WordNet might be able to generate plurals for *many* nouns… but it still won't help with most irregular nouns, like "children".

---

Anyway, the easy way to use WordNet from Python is via [NLTK](http://nltk.org). One of the NLTK HOWTO docs explains the [WordNet Interface](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html). (Of course it's even easier to just use NLTK without specifying a corpus, but that's not what you asked for.)

There is a lower-level API to WordNet called [`pywordnet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywordnet), but I believe it's no longer maintained (it became the foundation for the NLTK integration), and only works with older versions of Python (maybe 2.7, but not 3.x) and of WordNet (only 2.x).

Alternatively, you can always access the C API by using `ctypes` or `cffi` or building custom bindings, or access the Java API by using Jython instead of CPython.

Or, of course, you can call the command-line interface via `subprocess`.

---

Anyway, at least on some installations, if you give the simple Morphy interface a singular noun, it will return its plural, while if you give it a plural noun, it will return its singular. So:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
assert wn.morphy('dogs') == 'dog'
assert wn.morphy('dog') == 'dog'
```

This isn't actually documented, or even implied, to be true, and in fact it's clearly not true for the OP, so I'm not sure I'd want to rely on it (even if it happens to work on your computer).

The other way around *is* documented to work, so you could write some rules that apply all possible English plural rules, call `morphy` on each one, and the first one that returns the starting string is the right plural.

However, the way it's documented to work is effectively by blindly applying the same kind of rules. So, for example, it will properly tell you that `doges` is not the plural of `dog`—but not because it knows `dogs` is the right answer; only because it knows `doge` is a different word, and it likes the "+s" rule more than the "+es" rule. So, this isn't going to be helpful.

Also, as explained above, it has no rules for any irregular plurals—WordNet has no idea that  `children` and `child` are related in any way.

Also, `wn.morphy('reckless')` will return `'reckless'` rather than `None`. If you want that, you'll have to test whether it's a noun first. You can do this just sticking with the same interface, although it's a bit hacky:

```
def plural(word):
    result = wn.morphy(word)
    noun = wn.morphy(word, wn.NOUN)
    if noun in (word, result):
        return result
```

---

To do this properly, you will actually need to add a plurals database instead of trying to trick WordNet into doing something it can't do.

Also, a word can have multiple meanings, and they can have different plurals, and sometimes there are even multiple plurals for the same meaning. So you probably want to start with something like `(lemma for s in synsets(word, wn.NOUN) for lemma in s.lemmas if lemma.name == word)` and then get all appropriate plurals, instead of just returning "the" plural.

Comment: This seems generally correct. However, note that `wn.morphy('dog') == 'dogs'` equates to false on my current installation of NLTK, so it looks like `morphy()` does not appear to generate plural forms.

Comment: @Cerin: Well, given that it's not a documented feature of WordNet or NLTK, and that the FAQ explicitly says it can't do this, I guess I shouldn't be surprised that it doesn't work on your computer… I'll edit the answer to say that directly.

Comment: @Cerin: I've rolled back your edit, because `morphy('dog')` very clearly returns `'dogs'` on my installation, and the following text explains why you shouldn't rely on that (or the opposite) being true.

Comment: Well, it doesn't on my fresh installation of nltk 2.0.4, which is the most recent version. What version do you have installed? Per your own comments, it shouldn't be doing what you claim it's doing. And from morphy's help(), it finds "a possible base form for the given form". 'dogs' is in no way a base form of 'dog'.

Comment: if you're working on english, you dont really have to reinvent the wheel, they've done a well-coded and well-documented tool at http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#pluralization

Answer (score 0):

Most current pluralize libraries do not return multiple plurals for some irregular words. Some libraries do not enforce the passed parameter is noun and pluralize a word by general rules. So I decided to build a python library - [Plurals and Countable](https://github.com/Dictionary-video/Plurals-and-Countable), which is open source on github. The main purpose is to get plurals (yes, mutliple plurals for some words), and has an option to return dictionary approved plurals only. It can also return whether a noun is countable/uncountable or either way.

```
import plurals_counterable as pluc
pluc.pluc_lookup_plurals('octopus', strict_level='dictionary')
```

will return a dictionary of the following.

```
{
    'query': 'octopus', 
    'base': 'octopus', 
    'plural': ['octopuses', 'octopi', 'octopodes'], 
    'countable': 'countable'
}
```

If you query by a noun's plural, the return also tells which word is its base (singular or plural-only word).

The library actually looks up the words in dictionaries, so it takes some time to request, parse and return. Alternatively, you might use REST API provided by [Dictionary.video](https://dictionary.video). You'll need contact admin@dictionary.video to get an API key. The call will be like

```
import requests
import json
import logging

url = 'https://dictionary.video/api/noun/plurals/octopus?key=YOUR_API_KEY'
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    return json.loads(response.text)
else:
    logging.error(url + ' response: status_code[%d]' % response.status_code)
    return None
```