# How to have multiple strings in one input to print in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

I am not sure how to make this code print multiple inputs all plural. For example, if I type in the input "single-noun, single-noun, single-noun", it would print out as "single-noun, single-noun, plural-noun." For some reason, only the last string turns plural. How can I get it to print out "plural-noun, plural-noun, plural-noun?"

```
def double(noun):
    if noun.endswith("ey"):
        return noun + "s"    
    elif noun.endswith("y"):
        return noun[:-1] + "ies" 
    elif noun.endswith("ch"): 
        return noun + "es" 
    else:
        return noun + "s" 
noun = input("type in here")
print (double(noun))
```

Comment: I assume your `double` function is meant to be named `plural`.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902608/generating-the-plural-form-of-a-noun) has lots of good answers about making nouns plural (not answering your question).

Comment: @U9-Forward: I don't think it's a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` will return *the entire line* that the user entered.  That is, if the user types `bird, cat, dog`, your `plural` function will receive a string `"bird, cat, dog"` instead of being called with separate `"bird"`, `"cat"`, and `"dog"` strings individually.

You need to *tokenize* your input string.  A typical way to do this would be to use `str.split()` (and `str.strip()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace):

```
nouns = input("type in here").split(",")
for noun in nouns:
    print(plural(noun.strip()))
```

Or, if you want all of the results to be comma-separated and printed on one line:

```
nouns = input("type in here").split(",")
print(", ".join((plural(noun.strip()) for noun in nouns)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split`:

```
def double(nouns):
    l = []
    for noun in nouns.split(', '):
        if noun.endswith("ey"):
            l.append(noun + "s")   
        elif noun.endswith("y"):
            l.append(noun[:-1] + "ies")
        elif noun.endswith("ch"): 
            l.append(noun + "es")
        else:
            l.append(noun + "s")
    return ', '.join(l)
noun = input("type in here")
print (plural(noun))
```